# How to connect Meteor Js application with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I start work on fresh application of **MeteorJs** and facing problem with mongoDB connection with application and have research a lot regarding this but not get any proper solution.

I need to connect my **MeteorJs** Application with MongoDB and research about this issue but didn't get any solution.

Comment: can you please share your code? How you are trying it

Comment: I did write any code regarding connection i just watched an video in this video the database connection made via {MONGO_URL="URL" meteor run} command. and i try it but its not working for me.

Comment: Is it a production environment? If yes, you need to set the environment variable MONGO_URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Meteor Cloud then you should stick to the official docs: https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/mongodb.html#authentication

If you are using Meteor-Up (MUP) then you should check out the Mongo configuration: https://meteor-up.com/docs.html#mongodb

If you want to connect to a MongoDb with a custom deployment or your local development setup then you need to properly configure the `MONGO_URL`: https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#MONGO-URL

Don't forget to configure `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` as well: https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#MONGO-OPLOG-URL